# Why did front usb port not connecting to internet

Tags: usb, modem

My D-Link usb modem is not connecting to internet with front usb port. But it is working with the ports from rear side of the pc. And this front usb ports are perfect with pendrives and usb mouse. I can transfer data to my pendrive through this front usb. But i can't connect internet with this. When i plug the device in, it will detect the device and starts the modem software. But when i press the connect button, it shows an error msg. Like "PID Error 692".
My OS = Win8 32bit
Board = Asus P8H61 ML-X
Processor = Pentium G620 Dual core 64bit

Comment: Most likely, the case is old and the front USB ports are USB 1.1 ports with USB 1.1 cabling. If you connect a USB 2 device to them and they're connected to a USB 2 port on the motherboard, things won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious question that arises is:
**What is the difference between these two ports?**

When two ports seem identical, and both work fine with pendrives, I've come across power-issues: Depending on how the ports are connected internally, one possibility could be that they're on separate busses, one of which is unable to provide enough current. I've had this exact problem with a WD passport drive. While the drive is USB3, it is supposed to be backwards compatible with USB2, however, not all USB2 ports are able to provide enough current (Many vendors of low power devices skimp on the 500mA current spec dictated by the USB1.0 and 2.0 standard). Tablets and phones being typical examples of hosts that are limited in terms of available current for USB ports.

But I digress...

**Try connecting the modem via a powered USB HUB** (powered, as in, it has its own external power cable). This is a trick often used to solve the above mentioned current issue.

**Note:** Pendrives are relatively low-power devices, which is why they can work fine while other devices can't.

Comment: What if i use an usb extender cable and connect it to rear side usb port ?

Comment: @VinodKC If cable length is the only limiting factor, sure. If we're talking about a stationary computer here, the back ports are connected to the main USB bus directly, as opposed to whatever peripheral bus that feed to the front port, so I'm thinking that it should work a lot better.

Comment: I need to connect and re-connect this device into my pc often. So rear usb is not very easy place.